# generate a point cloud from a given depth image-matlab Computer Vision System Toolbox

Tags: matlab, kinect, matlab-cvst, depth, point-clouds

I am a beginner in matlab, I have purchased Computer Vision System Toolbox. I have being given 400 of depth images (.PNG images). I would like to create a point cloud for each image. I looked at the documentation of Computer Vision System Toolbox, and there is an example of converting depth image to point cloud (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/depthtopointcloud.html):

```
[xyzPoints,flippedDepthImage] = depthToPointCloud(depthImage,depthDevice)
depthDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('kinect',2)
```

but the thing that I don't understand is that it requires `Kinect camera` and `connection`. I am not connecting to Kinect, I don't have Kinect, I am just given the output of Kinect which are the depth images.

how to make use of the `function(depthToPointCloud)` in the toolbox in generating cloud points from already given depth images without connecting to Kinect camera?

Comment: have a look at that function http://rgbd-dataset.cs.washington.edu/software/depthToCloud.m

Comment: @gregswiss could you please explain the RGB-D camera constants: 'center = [320 240];' 'constant = 570.3; ' 'MM_PER_M = 1000;' the depth images come from Kinect v2

Comment: it's not my code but that's how I interpret it. center is the camera center in pixels, MM_PER_M is the number of mm per one meter. the constant must be the focal length in pixels (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `depthToPointCloud` function only works with Kinect v1, and it requires a connection to the Kinect to get the camera parameters.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what the three parameters in the depthToPointCloud function for the RGBD-object dataset mean ?